# Black screen will apear when Soft keyboard will close on surface view and also affected on Coverflow in the Fragment

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-softkeyboard, coverflow

I am using `Fragment` view in my application. And along with that at the top view I am using Surface view. I am opening soft keyboard on click of button. And then whatever I will write it must be showing on surface view. All thing working fine. But the issue is when I dismiss the soft keyboard one black screen will showing on background of my surface view.

If I used `surfaceview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPRENT)` then it will affected on my cover flow images. My images are not change frequently. It will affected when I open soft keyboard.

So I am not able to understand that how can I solve this problem? Is there any other solution to remove that Black screen?

Waiting for reply.

Comment: Hi, I know this is really old but did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue.